# bad request ao enviar número para Spring controller

Tags: formulário, spring-boot, controller

tenho um formulário que envia alguns dados para um controller, quando eu envio apenas dados de texto dá certo, mas quando envio um dado tipo number ( e que no controller espero receber como parametro um Double) dá erro de bad request. Se algum campo for enviado vazio, eu trato com jquery para identificar os campos vazios em um service (se o campo naõ for preenchido o jquery preenche com 'null' e aí o meu service entende que não foi preenchido).

Formulário

```
<form action="/pecas/teste" id="pesquisa">
                Descrição: 
                <input type="text" name="descricao" id="desc">
                Categoria:
                <input type="text" name="categoria" id="cat">
                Tamanho:
                <input type="text" name="categoria" id="tam">
                Cor:
                <input type="text" name="cor" id="cor">
                Preço:
                <input type="number" name="preco" id="preco">

                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

Jquery

```
$("#pesquisa").submit(function(){
            if($("#desc").val() == '')
                $("#desc").val('null');

            if($("#cat").val() == '')
                $("#cat").val('null');

            if($("#tam").val() == '')
                $("#tam").val('null');

            if($("#cor").val() == '')
                $("#cor").val('null');

            //como não sei o que está dando errado
            //não tô fazendo o tratamento para preco

        });
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(path="/teste")
public ModelAndView mostrarPecas(@RequestParam String descricao, @RequestParam String categoria, @RequestParam String cor,
        @RequestParam String tamanho, @RequestParam Double preco) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("verpecas");

    List<Peca> pecas = service.getPecas(descricao, categoria, tamanho, cor, preco);

    mv.addObject("pecas", pecas);

    return mv;
}
```

Comment: Olá! Nos informe qual a exception que o Spring dispara quando isto ocorre. Recomendo também usar `BigDecimal` ao invés de `Double` para valores monetários, para evitar problemas de precisão no futuro.

Comment: @Dherik, vlw pelo retornor! Consegui resolver, na verdade não era o preço que tava dando bad request, mas o tamanho, porque o "name" dele tava errado. Que tipo de problema eu posso ter com double?

Comment: explicação é um pouco extensa, mas pode conferir ela aqui (em inglês): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413493/2387977